# TypeScript return type based on class property

Tags: typescript, class, generics

I'd like a method without parameters that normally returns an array, or just the first element of that array when I know there will only be one item.

Note: I cannot change the shape or values of Thing, it's from an external app, I'm just creating a wrapper around the properties of Thing.

```js
interface Thing {
    [key: string]: any;
}

class Getter <T> {
    asArray: boolean;
    things: Thing[];
    prop: string;

    constructor(prop: string, things: Thing[], asArray: boolean) {
        this.asArray = asArray;
        this.things = things;
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    // THIS IS THE METHOD IN QUESTION
    getProp(): T | T[] {
        if (this.asArray) return things.map(t => t[this.prop]);
        else return things[0][this.prop];
    }

   // MORE METHODS ARE HERE FOR CHECKING DATA

}

class ThingModel {
    things: Thing[];
    asArray: boolean;

    constructor(asArray: boolean, ...things: Thing[]) {
        this.asArray = asArray;
        this.things = things;
    }

    get foo() {
        // We know the values of Thing.foo are numbers
        return new Getter<number>('foo', this.things, this.asArray);
    }

    get bar() {
        // We know the values of Thing.foo are strings
        return new Getter<string>('bar', this.things, this.asArray);
    }

}

const allThings = new ThingModel(true, ...getAllThings());
const oneThing = new ThingModel(false, getOneThing());

// TypeScript cannot infer these types, and both are the union of
// T | T[] even though we know which it will be, so the caller is
// forced to still make other assertions or type casts.
const allFooProps = allThings.foo.getProp(); // we know it's number[]
const oneBarProp = oneThing.bar.getProp(); // we know it's a string
```

If I stick to always returning an array, some calls are not so intuitive.

```js
// It's awkward that oneThing here would return an array of one property.
const [oneProp] = oneThing.foo.getProp();
```

I suppose I understand why this doesn't work out of the box - TypeScript likely cannot guarantee that `Getter.asArray` doesn't get changed after the constructor, however, I've tried using a readonly property for `asArray` as well, and it didn't help.

Overrides don't work because I have no parameters and I can't extend the class and override the method because it complains the return types aren't the same. I can't use generics, because I don't know the type yet at the constructor `new Getter(...)` without first checking the ThingModel.asArray property, and ThingModel can't have a generic, because the types of individual properties are all different.

The only way I can think to get this working is to define a SingleGetter class and re-implment every method of Getter, and then in `ThingModel` do an if/else for every property to construct the appropriate Getter or SingleGetter. I suppose that might be the most 'correct' way to do this - but it feels like a lot of excess code where Getter already has the right logic, just not a switch to return `values` or `values[0]`.

Is there an easier way to help the compiler know when I'm going to get a single value vs an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows, I'll be assuming that you're not better off refactoring to completely separate the "array" version of `Getter` and `ThingModel` from the "single" version.

You can make the `asArray` properties a generic type `A` that extends `boolean`, so that the compiler keeps track of whether or not it is `true` or `false`.

So your `Getter` class could look like:

```
class Getter<T, A extends boolean> {
    asArray: A;
    things: Thing[];
    prop: string;

    constructor(prop: string, things: Thing[], asArray: A) {
        this.asArray = asArray;
        this.things = things;
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    getProp(): A extends true ? T[] : T;
    getProp(): T | T[] {
        if (this.asArray) return this.things.map(t => t[this.prop]);
        else return this.things[0][this.prop];
    }
}
```

where the return type of `getProp()` is declared to be either `T[]` or `T` depending on the type of `A`.  Then your `ThingModel` would need to also be generic in `A`:

```
class ThingModel<A extends boolean> {
    things: Thing[];
    asArray: A;

    constructor(asArray: A, ...things: Thing[]) {
        this.asArray = asArray;
        this.things = things;
    }

    get foo() {
        return new Getter<number, A>('foo', this.things, this.asArray);
    }

    get bar() {
        return new Getter<string, A>('bar', this.things, this.asArray);
    }
}
```

You can see how we are just passing `A` from `ThingModel` into `Getter` inside the `foo()` and `bar()` methods.  And then your subsequent code will behave as you expect:

```
allThings.foo.getProp().map(x => x.toFixed());
oneThing.bar.getProp().toUpperCase();
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-RCA8HQ9JoLIInkVAnE8WoGmoTDClmWkDsUzePx1QweoJBD5RgtAyGJ1hefzBACoGd9QaSLgeEoN1ueFjuMPkfEILOpzXZ-O8el4PiIDv+-g4GPZy0U817o8djVmgiduoUch1GaVIADFgHUCBtF2fsj1nZo2zfTZtl2ICDAAVUCQJoAAYRECBdk4IA)